# UWP with AppService and periodical updating

Tags: c#, uwp

I am new to c# and uwp and currently I am developing a simple app to try out the app service in UWP.

What I would like to do is to create a UWP app with UI and some logic behind, then to connect to an app service (Windows Runtime Component), where I generate a number. This number is then displayed on the UI. It works just fine but I would like to extend this example with periodical updating - I want to change that number periodically (for example every five seconds).

I am asking for some help how to do this. I can use a timer to periodically send messages to the app service and receive responses with new numbers. But I actually don't like this approach.

Instead, I would like to use the timer directly in the app service and just periodically receive the responses in the main app. Is it be possible?

UPDATE

This is the method in AppService, which generates the random numbers and sends the response to the main app.

```
    private async void AppServiceConnection_RequestReceivedAsync(AppServiceConnection sender, AppServiceRequestReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        var deferral = args.GetDeferral();
        var requestMessage = args.Request.Message;
        var responseMessage = new ValueSet();
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        foreach (var item in requestMessage)
        {
            if (item.Value.ToString() == "k")
            {
                var task1 = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    responseMessage.Add(item.Value.ToString(), rand.NextDouble().ToString());
                });
                tasks.Add(task1);
            }

            if (item.Value.ToString() == "k2")
            {
                var task2 = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                        responseMessage.Add(item.Value.ToString(), rand.NextDouble().ToString());
                });
                tasks.Add(task2);
            }
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        await args.Request.SendResponseAsync(responseMessage);

        deferral.Complete();
    }
```

And this is the method in the main app, which periodically sends messages to the app service.

```
    private async void timerCallback(object state)
    {
        appServiceConnection = new AppServiceConnection
        {
            AppServiceName = "...",
            PackageFamilyName = "...";
        };

        var status = await appServiceConnection.OpenAsync();
        switch (status)
        {
            default:
                break;
        }

        var message = new ValueSet();
        message.Add("0", "k");
        message.Add("1", "k2");

        var response = await appServiceConnection.SendMessageAsync(message);
        switch (response.Status)
        {
            default:
                break;
        }

        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High,
            () => {
                randomNumbersString = string.Format("Task1: {0} \nTask2: {1}",
                    response.Message.Where((x) => x.Key == "k").First().Value.ToString(),
                    response.Message.Where((x) => x.Key == "k2").First().Value.ToString());
            });
```

It works as expected, however I would like to move the timer from the main app to the app service, is it possible?

Thank you very much

Comment: Please share what have you tried til now.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of using events. The `Window Runtime Component` should declare events something like `UpdateGUI`. You should subscribe to that event in main application.

Now use `task` to periodically raise event with appropriate parameters.

The sample code which can help you is provided as [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/walkthrough-creating-a-simple-windows-runtime-component-and-calling-it-from-javascript)